# Continuity at an Interval?

Tags: continuity

[image: Example 6 and Example 7.2]

Are example 6 and example 7.2 correct? 
Shouldn't be example 6 be (-infinity,1] U [1,+infinity), 
and should be example 7.2 be x≥4?

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Uh.  No....  If it is not defined for any $x > 1$ how can it be continuous at $x = 1$.

Comment: http://www.math.psu.edu/tseng/class/Math140A/Notes-Continuity.pdf

Comment: show your efforts...

Comment: In 7.2, $x=4$ is the point where the piecewise function breaks into pieces, so we must be careful there.  The analysis done in 7.2 only shows that $f(x)$ is continuous for $x > 4$.  The function is indeed continuous at $x=4$ also, but you have to show that by showing that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to4} f(x) = f(4)$.  To do that you need to evaluate both one-sided limits.  Also, what exactly is the question for #7?  It just says "consider the function..." and then goes into the solution.  Solution to what?  Largest interval of continuity again?

Comment: 7.1 is a temporary step to show that f is continuous for x > 4.  And 7.2 is a temporary step to show that f is continuous for x < 4.  I assume 7.3 will be a step to show that f is continuous *at* x = 4.  7.2 does not tell us anything about the continuity *at* x = 4.

Answer (score 0):

Your text is using the definition of continuous at $a$ to mean

$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = f(a)$.

for $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = K$ to be true two things must happen.  $\lim{x \to a; x > a} f(x) = K$ and $\lim{x\to a; x < a} f(x) = K$.

In 6)

$\lim_{x\to -1; x > -1} f(x)$ does not exist.  so $\lim_{x \to -1} f(x) \ne f(-1)$ so $f$ is not continuous at $x = -1$.  Likewise $\lim_{x\to 1; x < 1}f(x)$ does not exist so $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x) \ne f(1)$.

As for 7)

$\lim_{x\to 4; x > 4} = \lim_{x\to 4} x-1 = 3$ whil $\lim_{x\to 4; x < 4} = \sqrt{x} + 1 = 3$ and $f(4) = \sqrt{4} + 1 = 3$.  So $\lim_{x\to 4} f(x) = f(4)$ so $f$ is continuous at $4$.

.... and I assume that is step 3) on the next page.

7.1 is a temporary step to show that $f$ is continuous for $x > 4$.  And 7.2 is a temporary step to show that f is continuous for $x < 4$.  I assume 7.3 will be a step to show that f is continuous *at*$ x = 4$.  7.2 does not tell us anything about the continuity *at* $x = 4$.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. x=1 and x=-1 should be included in the solution for example 6 and x=4 should be included in the solution for 7.2. Functions are continuous at those points.

Comment: In 7, f is continuous at x=4 and I assume the text will show that in 7.3.  But in 6.  f is not continuous at x =1 or x= -1 because the limits are only one sides.  For any $\delta > 0$ then $-1 < x < -1 + \delta \implies |\sqrt{x^2-1} - f(-1)|$ does not exist.  Hence f is not continuous at $-1$.